# Regex to correctly match currency part in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to divide this kind of string into 3 groups

```
"02.01. 02.01. Pay card PN:123                                        6562,58 S"
```

group1 should match "02.01. 02.01."

group2 should match "Pay card PN:123                                        "

group3 should match "6562,58 S" (this part can vary by the amount i.e. 1,99 H )

my regex looks like this

```
^([0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\. [0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.)(.*)(\d+\,[0-9][0-9].*)
```

but group3 will only match "2,58 S" instead of "6562,58 S"

What is the correct regex ?

Comment: Instead of using `(.*)` to match the gap, use something that only excludes digits like `([^0-9]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, so it will match as much as possible. Either make it non-greedy or don't use `.` but `\s` for example.

I would also make the Regex as specific as possible, i.e. include the known strings. Since you seem to know about `\d`, I would use that over `[0-9]` for readability reasons.

```
^(\d\d\.\d\d\. \d\d\.\d\d\.)\s+(Pay card PN:\d+)\s+(\d+,\d\d [HS])$
```

That way you'll notice when your input changes and you potentially need to rework the Regex

```
^                             beginning of line
(\d\d\.\d\d\. \d\d\.\d\d\.)   dates
\s+                           whitespace as separator
(Pay card PN:\d+)             card number
\s+                           white space as separator
(\d+,\d\d [HS])               amount
$                             end of line
```

[Check it in RegexStorm.NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cd%5cd%5c.%5cd%5cd%5c.+%5cd%5cd%5c.%5cd%5cd%5c.%29%5cs%2b%28Pay+card+PN%3a%5cd%2b%29%5cs%2b%28%5cd%2b%2c%5cd%5cd+%5bHS%5d%29%24&i=02.01.+02.01.+Pay+card+PN%3a123++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++6562%2c58+S&o=m)

Comment: @MikeM: yes, I agree. Currencies probably don't have 3 digits after the comma